# base class 'QAbstractListModel' has private copy constructor

Tags: qt, qml, copy-constructor, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I have a QT QML project. (still very small)

I started by binding a listview on my `UScenario` model, by subclassing `QAbstractListModel` and it worked fined.

Now, each `UScenario` has a list of `UTask`, which also have a list of `UCondition` (so, `Utask` also subclasses `QAbstractListModel`). But then, QT Creator gives me an error:

```
Core/Tasks/utask.h:6: erreur : base class 'QAbstractListModel' has private copy constructor
class UTask: public QAbstractListModel
      ^
```

So I'm not sure where is my problem. I tried reading the doc about `QAbstractListModel` vs `QAbstractItemModel`, but I have no clue.

I also tried to see if I ever constructed a `UTask` in a wrong way; I think not.

```
// USCENARIO.h
#ifndef USCENARIO_H
#define USCENARIO_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include "../Tasks/utask.h"

class UScenario : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
     void cppSlot() { // Used to test the insertion from UI
         this->addTask(UTask());
     }

public:
    enum TaskRoles {
        IdRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };

    UScenario(QObject *parent = 0);

private:
    QList<UTask> m_tasks;

public:
    void addTask(const UTask &task);
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
};

#endif // USCENARIO_H



// USCENARIO.CPP

#include "uscenario.h"

UScenario::UScenario(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

void UScenario::addTask(const UTask &task)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_tasks.append(task);
    endInsertRows();
}

int UScenario::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    return m_tasks.count();
}

QVariant UScenario::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_tasks.count())
        return QVariant();

    const UTask &task = m_tasks[index.row()];
    if (role == IdRole)
        return task.id();

    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> UScenario::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[IdRole] = "id";
    return roles;
}






// UTASK.H
#ifndef UTASK_H
#define UTASK_H
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include "../Conditions/ucondition.h"

class UTask: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum TaskRoles {
        typeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };

    UTask(QObject *parent = 0);//:m_id(0){}
     int id() const{return m_id;}

private:
    int m_id;
    QList<UCondition> m_conditions;

    // QAbstractItemModel interface
public:
    void addCondition(const UCondition &cond);
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
};


#endif // UTASK_H







// UTASK.cpp
#include "utask.h"



UTask::UTask(QObject *parent):
    QAbstractListModel(parent), m_id(0)
{

}

void UTask::addCondition(const UCondition &cond)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_conditions.append(cond);
    endInsertRows();
}

int UTask::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return m_conditions.count();

}

QVariant UTask::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_conditions.count())
        return QVariant();

    const UCondition &cond = m_conditions[index.row()];
    if (role == typeRole)
        return cond.type();

    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> UTask::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[typeRole] = "type";
    return roles;
}


// MAIN
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <qqmlengine.h>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>
#include "../uCtrlCore/Scenario/uscenario.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    UScenario scenarioModel;
    scenarioModel.addTask(UTask());
    scenarioModel.addTask(UTask());
    scenarioModel.addTask(UTask());

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    QQmlContext *ctxt = viewer.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myScenarioModel", &scenarioModel);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/uCtrlDesktopQml/main.qml"));

    QObject *item = viewer.rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("btn");
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal()), &scenarioModel, SLOT(cppSlot()));

    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There problem is with how you're storing the `UTask` objects in your `UScenario` class

```
QList<UTask> m_tasks
```

In simple terms when you call `m_tasks.append` it is attempting to allocate a new `UTask` object in the `QList` by copying the source `UTask` object via the default copy constructor. In the case of `QAbstractListModel` it is private. This is why you're at getting the error.

A simply solution is to change the storage type to a list of `UTask` pointers, `QList< UTask* >` along with the supporting code to properly release the memory when your `UScenario` object is destroyed.

For example here are some but not all of the changes but should point you in the right direction. Just make sure to change `m_tasks` to `QList< UTask* >` first:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...

    UScenario scenarioModel;
    scenarioModel.addTask( new UTask() );
    scenarioModel.addTask( new UTask() );
    scenarioModel.addTask( new UTask() );

    ...    

    return app.exec();
}

void UScenario::cppSlot() 
{ 
     // Used to test the insertion from UI
     this->addTask( new UTask() );
}

// Change the signature to take a pointer
void UScenario::addTask( UTask* task )
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_tasks.append(task);
    endInsertRows();
}

// Make sure you define a destructor for UScenario
UScenario::~UScenario()
{
    QList< UTask* >::iterator task = m_tasks.begin();

    while( m_tasks.end() != task )
    {
        // Release the memory associated with the task.
        delete (*task);
        ++task;
    }

    m_tasks.clear();
}
```